# I want to Train 4 more Word2vec models and average the resulting embedding matrices

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, gensim

I wrote the code below, I used Used spacy to restrict the words in the tweets to content words, i.e., nouns, verbs, and adjectives. Transform the words to lower case and add the POS with an underderscore. E.g.:

love_VERB old-fashioneds_NOUN

now I want to Train 4 more Word2vec models and average the resulting embedding matrices.
but I dont have any idea for it, can you help me please ?

```
# Tokenization of each document
from gensim.models.word2vec import FAST_VERSION
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import spacy
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
import wget

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/reviews.full.tsv.zip'
wget.download(url, 'reviews.full.tsv.zip')

with ZipFile('reviews.full.tsv.zip', 'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall()

# nrows , max amount of rows
df = pd.read_csv('reviews.full.tsv', sep='\t', nrows=100000)
documents = df.text.values.tolist()

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # you can use other methods
# excluded tags
included_tags = {"NOUN", "VERB", "ADJ"}


vocab = [s for s in new_sentences]

sentences = documents[:103]  # first 10 sentences
new_sentences = []
for sentence in sentences:
    new_sentence = []
    for token in nlp(sentence):
        if token.pos_ in included_tags:
            new_sentence.append(token.text.lower()+'_'+token.pos_)
    new_sentences.append(new_sentence)


# initialize model
w2v_model = Word2Vec(
                     size=100,
                     window=15,
                     sample=0.0001,
                     iter=200,
                     negative=5,
                     min_count=1,  # <-- it seems your min_count was too high
                     workers=-1,
                     hs=0
                     )


new_sentences


w2v_model.build_vocab(vocab)

w2v_model.train(vocab, 
                total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, 
                epochs=w2v_model.epochs)
w2v_model.wv['car_NOUN']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to average together vectors from multiple training runs; it is more likely to destroy any value from the individual runs than provide any benefit.

No one run creates the 'right' final positions, nor do they all approach some idealized positions. Rather, each just creates a set-of-vectors that is internally comparable to others in that same co-trained set. Comparisons or combinations with vectors from other, non-interleaved training runs are usually going to be nonsense.

Instead, aim for one adequate run. If vectors move around a lot, in repeated runs, that's normal. But each reconfiguration should be about as useful, if used for word-to-word comparisons, or analysis of word neighborhoods/directions, or as input to downstream algorithms. If they vary wildly in usefulness, there are likely other inadequacies in the data or model parameters. (For example: too little data – word2vec requires lots to give meaningful results – or a model that's too large for the data – making it prone to overfitting.)

Other observations about your setup:

- Just 103 sentences/texts is tiny for word2vec; you shouldn't expect the vectors from such a run to have any of the value that the algorithm would usually provide. (Running such a tiny dataset might be helpful for verifying no halting-errors in the process, or familiarize yourself with the steps/APIs, but the results will tell you nothing.)
- `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea in word2vec and similar algorithms. Words that only appear once (or a few times) don't have the variety of subtly-different uses that are needed to train it into a balanced position against other words – so they wind up with weak/strange final positions, and the sheer number of such words dilutes the training effectiveness for other more-frequent words. The common practice of discarding rare words usually gets better results.
- `iter=200` is an extreme choice which is typically only valuable to try to squeeze results out of inadequate data. (In such a case, you might also have to reduce the vector-`size` from normal 100-plus dimensions.) So if you seem to need that, getting more data should be a top priority. (Using 20x more data is far, far better than using 20x more iterations on smaller data – but involves the same amount of training time.)

Comment: thank you , But I want to do it as an exercise for my programming skills, so thats why I need this, can you help me with that?

Comment: Fair enough, but in my experience nonsense code like that – that a novice might think is meaningful – tends to echo across forums, and low-quality "tutorials", and so forth. So especially in a place designed to help beginners, like StackOverflow, I don't want to publish or encourage meaningless or unwise calculations.